# Порядок инициализации классов в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, порядок инициализации классов в Kotlin. Допустим есть два класса A  и B. В main вызываем класс B:

```
open class A (val a:Int) {
    val a2 = 10
    init{
        println("init A")
    }

    constructor(s:String):this(3)  {
        println("Secondary constructor class A")
    }

}

class B(b:Int):A(b) {
    val b = 20
    init{
        println("class B")
    }
    constructor(s:String):this(3)  {
        println("Secondary constructor class B")
    }

}

fun main(){
  val b = B(100)
}
```

Я думаю порядок вызова будет такой:

1. primary constructor дочернего класса
2. pimary constructor родительского класса
3. поля родительского класса
4. init блок родительского класса
5. поля потомка
6. init блок дочернего класса

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно, сначала вызовется конструктор дочернего класса `B`, который затем активирует конструктор родительского класса `A`. После этого сначала выполняется инициализация базового класса (код в `init{}`, методы, поля и т.д.), и лишь только тогда происходит инициализация производного класса.

Дело в том, что некоторые методы, а также свойства дочернего класса могут оверрайдить (переопределять) такие же значения родительского класса, поэтому, если сначала будет инициализация дочернего класса, могут возникнуть определённые проблемы в виде странного поведения или даже сбоя.

Проще говоря, порядок, приведённый Вами, правильный, но есть одно уточнение: `init`'ы и поля обрабатываются в порядке нахождения в классе, поэтому, стоит внимательно следить, чтобы во время `init` не было ещё несуществующих членов класса.

Более подробно про наследование в Kotlin можно прочесть здесь: https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/inheritance.html